# counting vowel with find() and string::npos

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
ifstream inf(argv[1]);
if (!inf)
 {
    cerr << "Error opening " << argv[1] <<  endl;
    return 1;
 }

char ch;
size_t count = 0;

string vowels = "aAeEiIoOuU";
size_t p;
p = vowels.find(ch);

inf >> ch;
while(!inf.eof())
{


    if (p != string::npos)
    {
        count++;
    }
 inf >> ch;      
}     


inf.close();
cout << "File " << argv[1] << " includes " << count << " vowels." << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I have problem with the part

```
 inf >> ch;
while(!inf.eof())
{
  if ( p != string::npos)
  {
    count++
  }
       inf >> ch;
}
```

Basically, the program look up the text.txt file and count how many vowels it have.
I want to repeat inside of while loop. If I include "inf >> ch;" at the end of the while loop, the program counts the vowel wrong. If I do not, the program freezes when I run it. Can you please help me? Thank you.

hints :

I have to use

1. string vowels = "aAeEiIoOuU";
2. the function call vowels.find(ch) will return an index that is not string::npos if ch is a vowel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: @Ben I do not think so.  It is a problem but they have a bigger problem with `p = vowels.find(ch);`

Comment: Rather than use a manual loop at all, consider using [`std::count_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) instead, using [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) for input, and a predicate function that checks for vowel characters.

Comment: Thank you guys all. I solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you call `find` outside of the loop, so possible fix is:

```
string vowels = "aAeEiIoOuU";
// p delcaration and call to find is removed from here
inf >> ch;
while(!inf.eof())
{
    size_t p = vowels.find(ch);
    if (p != string::npos)
    {
        count++;
    }
    inf >> ch;      
}
```

but to avoid code duplicate this is better and cleaner:

```
while( inf >> ch )
{
    size_t p = vowels.find(ch);
    if (p != string::npos)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

In this bit of code:

```
char ch;
...
p = vowels.find(ch);
```

You use `ch` without it being initialized. How can you know what the result of this program will be. Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).